# Where does the word 'reactionary' come from?

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown

I am interested in the origin of this word, strictly in the political usage of the word (Reactionary = conservative, right-wing). The definition is simple enough:

Reactionary: *Characterized by reaction, especially opposition to progress or liberalism; extremely conservative.*

This seems to be a designation of someone who is opposed to political revolution. Is this word more of an insult than a descriptive term?

"Oh they are *just* a reactionary... no original ideas, just reacting to the idea of progress."

What I am really interested in why the right-wing of politics are called 'Reactionaries'. Surely both sides of politics are reacting to social/political/religious structure/movements? To me, the word conservative is a better fit.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're looking for a definition or an origin.

Comment: @HotLicks - thanks, edit made for clarity.

Comment: It's a term from the French Revolution, IIRC. It's the opposite pole from *revolutionary*.I'm sure this question will yield to a web search.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Reactionary" derives from the French word réactionnaire (a late 18th century coinage based on the word réaction, "reaction")...

What I am really interested in is the reason for the word 'Reaction'? To me 'Conservatism' makes more sense as you are conserving the present state of society. But the original derivation of 'reactionary' doesn't appear to apply to specifically Right-wing politics. Left-wing revolutionaries could be 'reacting' to the *current* state of society.

Comment: @TheLastGIS If you've looked up the origin of *reactionary*, then add that to your question—and clarify what you're actually interested in. [*Reaction*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reaction) can apply to many different things, including political beliefs. Why should the related *reactionary* not take on that meaning? Also note that *reactionary* doesn't only apply to politics, even if that's a common context for it.

Comment: This use of _reaction_ to refer to opposition to political and social (not to speak of philosophical) views is a reaction to the Enlightenment.

Comment: Thank you @JohnLawler. That is more or less what I expected to find. Do you have any sources?

Comment: Check the dates and sources for the citations in the OED. Words don't fall far from their speakers. And it should be noted that it's a euphemism; it's used instead of a clear description of motives, and without specifying exactly what's being reacted to.

Comment: Sidenote~ My experience with world politics taught me one thing. Conservative is just a label - I have seen conservatives vs liberal supporting vastly completely opposing sides based on geography and all that comes with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term of French origin appears to have been first used in the current sense by mid-19th century in Marxist use:

[Reactionary:](http://1831,%20on%20model%20of%20French%20r%C3%A9actionnaire%20(19c.),%20from%20r%C3%A9action%20(see%20reaction).%20In%20Marxist%20use,%20%22tending%20toward%20reversing%20existing%20tendencies,%22%20opposed%20to%20revolutionary%20and%20used%20opprobriously%20in%20reference%20to%20opponents%20of%20communism,%20by%201858.%20As%20a%20noun,%20%22person%20considered%20reactionary,%22%20especially%20in%20politics,%20one%20who%20seeks%20to%20check%20or%20undo%20political%20action,%20by%201855.)

> 1831, on model of French réactionnaire (19c.), from réaction (see reaction). ***In Marxist use, "tending toward reversing existing tendencies," opposed to revolutionary and used opprobriously in reference to opponents of communism, by 1858***. As a noun, "person considered reactionary," especially in politics, one who seeks to check or undo political action, by 1855.

(Etymonline)

Comment: This seems to be a good explaination of its origin and where the 'reaction' part of 'reactionary' comes from. Thank you.